# Edit specific html data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, custom-data-attribute

I want to edit a certain html data attribute

```
data-i18n="[title]tt.navigation_cube_control
```

on this website "http://potree.org/potree/examples/lion.html" with css/jquery etc but every time I try to edit it, nothing happens. I've tried

```
getAttribute("data-i18n=[title]tt.navigation_cube_control");
```

also

```
#navigation img:nth-child(6)
```

but thats not working for me. I am trying to just hide that specific "navigation cube" on click and also move it around in css but its not working for me. I tried finding the file they're using on developer tools but I can't find it. I downloaded their example codes and tried it that way and it still doesnt work. I think the problem is I have the attribute name wrong when I call it.

What I want to do is be able to hide/move around the navigation cube on the website above using the data attribute name.

Comment: getAttribute gets you the attribute of an element, not a way to find an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) lets you get the value of an attribute of an element, it is NOT a way to reference an element. You can see that in the documentation.

If you want to get an element by that attribute and value, you would use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to reference it.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('[data-i18n="[title]tt.navigation_cube_control"]')
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<div data-i18n="[title]tt.navigation_cube_control">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getAttribute` will get the *value* of an attribute given the *name* of the attribute.

So you would use: `someElement.getAttribute("data-i18n");`

… but you want to set the value, not get it, so you need `setAttribute`:

```
someElement.setAttribute("data-i18n", "your new value");
```